# Euclidean Distance Formula in sas

Tags: sas

[image]

hi i want ti implement this formula in sas, i have values for q1 & p1 which are customer co-ordinates and q2 & p2 which are store coordinates. by using this formula i want to calculate the distance between store and customers.

so for i have used this

```
DATA D2.FINAL;
SET D2.final;
DIST = SQRT(((q1 - p1)*(q1 - p1))+((q2 - p2)*(q2 - p2))); 
RUN;
```

which i believe is might not be correct way.

Comment: What evidence is suggesting the computation is not the correct way ?  For a human pathing result you can ask google to compute distances. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [GEODIST()](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n1korpfg2e18lon1nwpow9qijdxe.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n17q4pp2gkomrrn1cn970nfm7q3x) built in function

```
data _null_;
   distance=geodist(30.68, -88.25, 35.43, -82.55, 'M');
   put 'Distance = ' distance 'miles';
run;
```

SAS writes the following output to the log:

> Distance = 465.29081088 miles

**Alternative 1:** uses the [zipcitydistance()](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n1r333fdkrofhxn10vmhu9bq5m85.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) function if you have the zip codes for each of the locations. It isn't as specific as latitude and longitude but it's easily available.

**Alternative 2:** If you want driving time distances the [last post in this thread](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Extracting-column-values-into-a-variable/td-p/628254/page/2) illustrates how to get it using the Google API. You will need an API key and Google provides a certain amount of free credits a month. If you go beyond that amount you will have to pay. You have to enter a credit card but you can set it to not bill you unless you want to.

Comment: I did not even know `zipcitydistance()` was a function. That is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

DIST_FROM_STORE = (SQRT(((STORE_X - CUSTOMER_X)**2)+((STORE_Y - CUSTOMER_Y)**2)));

this worked for me

Comment: Good you found your answer. For other methods, you can use Proc Distance or IML.